# c# how to create List<> of columns from another List<> with dynamic column names

Tags: c#, linq

Here the scenario:

1. I load date from db and got a `List <productModel> products` - this one
   have 80 columns...
2. and I have `DataTable productsColumnsNames` where the User can definite witch columns want to see later in DataGrid.
3. Everything happens dynamically so here is my problem... for example the User choose col4, col7, col8, col26, col55 (columns name) how I can get the result in new or the List?

I reading a lot about this online I sow couple of different solusions but not one working with my problem...
One of solutions is this one (come from other example for for ListView) and of course don´t working with List but will be great is possible to modified for my code

```
var columnNames = new List<string> { colName1, colName3, colName3 };

var columnsToDelete = productsa.Where(c => !columnNames.Contains(c.Name));

foreach (var column in columnsToDelete)
{
    ResultsLogTab_ListView.Columns.Remove(column);
}
```

Comment: Rather than creating a new `List` can you go direct to a `DataGrid`? You can build a `DataGrid` with just the columns you need but to build a `List` you need an actual `Type` that has those columns.

Comment: That List is not going to help much.  Use CheckedListBox or a ListView with CheckBoxes = true to let the user select the columns.

Comment: Hallo Ian Mercer - you idea is good but dynamically ? It´s possible ?

Comment: You could create a new `DataTable` copying the columns not to be deleted, then copy all the rows from the source to the `DataTable`, then using it in the `DataGrid`. But it depends on what you will do with the `DataGrid`. You could also handle the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event and cancel creation of columns to be delted.

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering the products list using the column names. You should be filtering the products list only if you want to exclude certain products.

In this case, you can create a new list with only the required columns and copy from the first list to second for all rows. You can also use automapper to map the two lists, but the second list needs to be defined first.

Comment: nice nice... BUT now ?